# Angular 2 plus, multi-developer, TFVC and node_modules

Tags: angular, tfs, npm, azure-devops, node-modules

Given that node_modules is 20000+ files it doesn't seem appropriate to add them to source control.

This means that every time a dev does a get latest they will have to run npm install to download any missing modules

Is there any way to automate this so as when they do a get latest an npm install occurs?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: not at the moment but I am going to evaluate it - would it be better to use this? just currently TFS only

Comment: sorry i thought u said git for tfs - thinking about evaluating this.... using tfvc in VS 2017 and VSTS for VS Code (wanting to get away from full VS)

Comment: As Daniel said that there isn't the way to do it in VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, package restoring (whether it's NuGet in the .NET world, or NPM) is built into a build script of some kind -- you grab the source code, run your build script, and it goes and does everything necessary to produce a build and run the tests.

It's considered a good practice to do this before you start changing code, anyway -- better to know **before** you start writing code if someone else somehow snuck in non-building code or something that broke unit tests.

This is a long way of saying "nope, you can't do that with TFVC."